# How to write oracle insert query for return value in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I wrote query which I got no return value as follows:

```
  con.Open();
  OracleCommand  cmd= CreateCommand();
  cmd.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO {"Customer".GetDoubleQuoted()}({"City".GetDoubleQuoted()},{"CompanyName".GetDoubleQuoted()} , {"ContactName".GetDoubleQuoted()} ,{"Country".GetDoubleQuoted()},{"CustomerID".GetDoubleQuoted()},{"Phone".GetDoubleQuoted()}) VALUES ('Chicago', 'Amisys','Jwk', 'USA','aaa', '123456') \n Returning {"City".GetDoubleQuoted()} into :city";
  cmd.Connection = con;
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter
  {
       ParameterName = ":city",
       OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
       Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
   });
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  var value= cmd.Parameters[":city"].Value.ToString();
```

Could someone help me finding out why value doesn't come out?

Thanks in advance.
joon

Comment: Try setting the ParameterDirection to ReturnValue

Comment: Thanks Roy, but it doesn't make any change at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is a small gotcha in ODP.NET, everytime you receive a `varchar2` `returnValue` parameter you must specify the size. So simply adding the line `Size=32000,` to your example will make it work.

See the full code bellow:

```
 con.Open();
 OracleCommand  cmd= CreateCommand();
 cmd.CommandText = $@"INSERT INTO {"Customer".GetDoubleQuoted()(
        {"City".GetDoubleQuoted()},
        {"CompanyName".GetDoubleQuoted()},
        {"ContactName".GetDoubleQuoted()},
        {"Country".GetDoubleQuoted()},
        {"CustomerID".GetDoubleQuoted()},
        {"Phone".GetDoubleQuoted()}
     ) VALUES ('Chicago', 'Amisys','Jwk', 'USA','aaa', '123456')
     Returning {"City".GetDoubleQuoted()} into :city";
 cmd.Connection = con;
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter
     {
         ParameterName = ":city",
         OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
         Size = 32000,
         Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
     });
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 var value= cmd.Parameters[":city"].Value.ToString();
```

Note: `32000` is the maximum size for a `varchar2` column.

Comment: Thanks Roy, I got return value as expected. Thanks again.